# Max files per directory on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm currently storing ~3 million images files in a single directory on my server, which is  causing serious performance issues. I'd like to move them to Amazon S3 and I'm wondering whether I'd need to use a hierarchical folder structure or whether I can store them in a single folder on S3.

I get a large percentage of my traffic from google image search and I don't want to hurt my SEO by changing the image path, so a single folder on S3 would be ideal if there aren't any performance issues. I imagine LIST operations would be slow, but I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

S3 has no limit on the number of items stored in a bucket. In fact, using a 'directory' separator in key names is completely optional.

There is a practical use for using a separator in your key: as you correctly guessed listing the keys will be more difficult as you'll have to page though many list results.

However, as the [S3 documentation points](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?ListingKeysHierarchy.html) out you can use *any* character as a separator.